# How to iterate through every document in every collection in Firestore?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say my app has a collection for every restaurant that uses it. Each document for each collection is basically a type of food that has an expiration time stamp on it. What I need to do it query through every 'food' in every 'restaurant' and delete each 'food' if the current time that I get from my node js server is past the expiration time stamp. What is an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a HTTP Request trigger Cloud Function that you can invoke by cron. ie. https://cron-job.org/

With this cloud function you should use the Admin JS SDK to loop through collections and fetch all documents.

You can get all collections with the function `getCollections()` See https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.9.x/Firestore#getCollections

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
try {
  admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)
} catch (e) {} 
const db = admin.firestore()
export const getCollections = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
  const collections = await db.getCollections()
  res.status(200).send(collections.map(collection => collection.id))
})
```

Comment: Ok thanks - I saw this same method on the firestore docs here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data , but it said that it would only retrieve all subcollections of a collection so I thought it would not work. Anyway ...

Comment: I am using this procedure in a backup script it works

Comment: I am initilazing my db in node js as  var db = admin.firestore();

When I run 

 db.getCollections().then(collections => {
    collections.forEach(collection => {
        console.log('Found subcollection with id:', collection.id);
    });
       
       return "success";
       
}).catch(errors);

I get Error: could not handle the request on the http endpoint where its hosted.

Comment: I added an example of a working cloud functions that returns all root collections in your firestore database.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the error you get. It however doesn't seem to be firestore related. Please provide more code.

Comment: Here is a link to basically the whole index.js file I am using @troels lenda

https://jsfiddle.net/b80e0geg/

Comment: Your code looks fine. where and how do you get the error "could not handle the request on the http endpoint where its hosted" ? Did you try to deploy? are you serving on localhost?

Comment: It deploys successfully - the node js server runs at 
https://grubyr-new.firebaseapp.com/
and the function triggers at 
https://grubyr-new.firebaseapp.com/deals
which is where i get the error that it cant handle the request 

@troels lenda

Comment: `catch(e)`... e is not defined. when you call catch like this youre trying to pass e as an argument. Please try with `catch(e => console.log(e))`

Comment: or `catch(function(e) { console.log(e) })`

Comment: How can I iterate over `var test=  admin.firestore().collection('users');` ?

Comment: Hi farahm.
admin.firestore().collection('users').get() returns a q
uerySnapshot Promise with all the documents in your collection.
https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/411002d14a071b2d3ec6f74bd88fabe309518d1b/firestore/test.firestore.js#L601-L606